# ProGuard unresolved reference in Shrinker Config file

Tags: android, proguard

Each of these lines in the Proguard file

```
-keep class android.webkit.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.ads.internal.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil {*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info {*;}
```

produces an Android Shrinker error:

> Unresolved class name / unresolved reference in Shrinker Config file

How can these errors be fixed?

(I'm using Android Api 29 and AndroidStudio 4.0.)

**Edit**: When I replace the '**' wildcard by just '*', the first two error messages are gone.
Also, when the '$' is replaced by a dot, the subclass AdvertisingIdClient$Info is found.

Maybe it is a bug in Android Shrinker.

[image: unresolved class name]

Comment: 1) `android.webkit` is part of the Android SDK and runtime. It's not in your app, so there's nothing to keep. 2) Why do you think you need the rest?

Comment: These rules helped to work around some bugs in ad sdks.

Answer (score 20):

This is a bug that came with Android Studio 4.0 : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153616200

It hasn't been resolved yet, but you can temporarily remove the warning by adding

```
#noinspection ShrinkerUnresolvedReference
```

at the beginning of your Proguard file.

Comment: Yes possibly it is a bug, as it did not happen before in previous versions of Android Studio.
Now that I have version 4.0.1, it started to cause this error.

Comment: Is this still an ongoing bug?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky As of AS 4.0.1, yeap. Looks like they [fixed it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153616200#comment17) just haven't been rolled out yet